# Will I get OTA updates from Vodaphone Australia by flashing stock I9300XXEMC2 ROM on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, odin

I have an Australian Samsung Galaxy S3 from Vodafone (GT-i9300T). I want to flash a non-branded ROM to it using Odin. I found a ROM on samfirmware.com called `I9300XXEMC2`. Will I be able to get OTA updates if I install this? It is a stock ROM, but I've read that it might have problems if the modem and CSC don't match up.

Here are the details of the rom:
GT-I9300 Galaxy S III
PDA: I9300XXEMC2
CSC: I9300XSAEMC2
MODEM: I9300XXEMC2
Added: 2013-03-28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be able to get OTA updates if I install this?

CSC of `XSA` or `VUA` works for Australia. As long as it's stock ROM, you should be able to get OTA update. If it doesn't work, try to update via Kies on your PC.

> I've read that it might have problems if the modem and CSC don't match
>   up.

It's OK for modem and CSC to be different, but CSC must be correct if you want OTA updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I flash that rom will it update my CSC or do I have to do that seperately?

Comment: @Jai The ROM you mentioned has XSA CSC. That should be OK. No need to flash a separate CSC.